# Mongodb removing element inside subarray

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My question is how to remove an element with a specified id inside an array.

DB structure:

```
const userScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    login: String, password: String, surveys: [{
        _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, inquirer: [
            {
                _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                question: String,
                answers: [String]
            }
        ]
    }], statistics: [
        {
            _inquirerId: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, surveyAnswers: [Number]
        }
    ]
});
```

**surveys** column:

```
[
  {
    "_id": new
    ObjectId(
    "63692b8dda87c344d03dae3d"
    ),
    "inquirer": [
      {
        "_id": new
        ObjectId(
        "63692b8dda87c344d03dae39"
        ),
        "question": "Question 4",
        "answers": [
          "option 1",
          "option 2",
          "option 3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": new
        ObjectId(
        "63692b8dda87c344d03dae3a"
        ),
        "question": "Question 5",
        "answers": [
          "option 1",
          "option 2",
          "option 3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": new
        ObjectId(
        "63692b8dda87c344d03dae3b"
        ),
        "question": "Question 6",
        "answers": [
          "option 1",
          "option 2",
          "option 3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to remove Question 6 from the inquirer by id

```
db.users.updateOne({"surveys.inquirer._id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae39")},
{$pull: {"surveys.inquirer": {"_id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae39")}}});
```

This code is not working. Also I need to update a question and answers:

```
db.users.findOneAndUpdate({
"surveys.inquirer._id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae39"),
}, { $set: {
"surveys.$.inquirer.question": "new question",
"surveys.$.inquirer.answers": ["one", "two", "three"]
}});
```

This approach also does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried the code, which I provide at the question, but it does not work

Comment: For the removal, you said you are trying to `pull` question six, but that id is for question 4. At a glance, I don't see anything wrong with the syntax, so I would just double check that it's not just removing the wrong element.

Comment: My bad, I tried to remove "Question 4" by specified id. 
first query returns
Write error: WriteError{code=28, message='Cannot use the part (inquirer) of (surveys.inquirer) to traverse the element.

Second one: 
Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: Cannot create field 'answers' in element

Answer (score 0):

Updating:

```
        db.users.updateOne({}, {
            $set: {
                "surveys.$[surveys].inquirer.$[inquirer].question": "Test new String",
                "surveys.$[surveys].inquirer.$[inquirer].answers": ['1', '2', '3']
            }
        }, {
            arrayFilters: [{
                "surveys._id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae3d")
            }, {
                "inquirer._id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae39")
            }]
        })
```

Deleting by id:

```
db.users.updateOne({}, {
    $pull: {
        "surveys.$[surveys].inquirer": {
            "_id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae3a")
        }
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        "surveys._id": ObjectId("63692b8dda87c344d03dae3d")
    }]
})
```